# How to remove the first element of sub-list in prolog

Tags: prolog

List like this:`[1,[2,3,4]]`
Remove the first element of sub-list which is 2,
Result like this:`[1,[3,4]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you an idea of how to do it:

```
rem_sublist_first([], []).

rem_sublist_first([X|Y], [X|Y2]):-
    \+ X = [_|_],
    rem_sublist_first(Y, Y2).

rem_sublist_first([[_|Y1]|Y2], [Y1|Y3]):-
    rem_sublist_first(Y2, Y3).

test:-
    rem_sublist_first([1,[2,3,4]], [1,[3,4]]),
    rem_sublist_first([1,2,3,[4,5,6]], [1,2,3,[5,6]]).
```

I advise you to study prolog lists, they are essential for any type of prolog program so it is a worth investment if you are goind to write prolog code.

Comment: what's the meaning of this sentence " \+ X = [_|_], "?thanks bro:)

Comment: It means "negation", or "not provable/unifiable". Without the negation there the clause would match on sublists as well, which we do not want, the sublists should match on the clause below only. No problem :)